# how to rename package name in a flutter project

Tags: flutter

I have added  `rename: ^2.0.1` and gave pub get. then I run this command

> pub global run rename --bundleId com.hit.fantomcarpentry

but Im getting below error,

> 'pub' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

how to correct this. I want to change my package name.

current package name

> package="com.hit.fixing_to_do"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this command, you should include flutter before pub in command and make sure you are in the project directory:

```sh
flutter pub global run rename --bundleId com.hit.fantomcarpentry
```

If not work follow alternative solution:

You can use [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name).

To use this, add this package in pubsec.yaml

```yaml
dev_dependencies: 
  change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0
```

Not migrated to null safety yet? use old version like this

```yaml
dev_dependencies: 
  change_app_package_name: ^0.1.3
```

then run this command in project directory:

```sh
flutter pub get
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

Comment: If I do this does it create a new package (new url) on pub.dev or does it use the existing url/package location on pub just with a different name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

Add below in your pubspec.yaml file, save your file.

```
dev_dependencies: 
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
```

and Run this command to change package name

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```